# copy event into my calendar and extend to the hole week

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to find the next Good Friday ("Karfreitag"), create a new event in my calendar and extend to the hole holy week.

I found some good examples on SO, and adjusted to:

```
    function copyHoliday() {  
      var calRebate    = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('_____________________@group.v.calendar.google.com');     // external (rebate periods)
      var calHoliday   = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('de.christian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com');     // external (holiday periods)
      var searchStart = new Date('2021','0','1');
      var searchEnd   = new Date(searchStart.getDate() + (365 * 24  * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      Logger.log(searchStart ,searchEnd);
      var  officialKarEvent = calHoliday.getEvents(searchStart,searchEnd,{search: 'Karfreitag'});
      var  myKarEvent  = calRebate.createAllDayEvent('Karwoche',officialKarEvent.getAllDayStartDate()-4,officialKarEvent.getAllDayEndDate()+2);  
    return(myKarEvent);  
    }
    
    
    function main() {
      Logger.log(copyHoliday()); 
    }
```

Failure:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createAllDayEvent' of null

Somehow my officialKarEvent does not return an event.

Is this because there may be theoretically more than one event in the search, and the script does not know which to process?

Thank You for Your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should only have one event since there are no other events named `Karfreitag`. But to be sure, what I did was check if it was the exact title of the event.

Upon checking the supplied calendar, I copied the title of that and then used in my code below.

Also, your subtraction on `createAllDayEvent` dates are only modifying in milliseconds. So the safe way to adjust it is via `setDate` and `getDate`.

#### Code:

```
function copyHoliday() {
  var calendarSource = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('de.christian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com');
  var calendarDestination = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('destination calendar');
  var start = new Date('2021','0','1');
  // Sometimes, years are not 365 days, so better spell it out
  var end = new Date('2021','11','31');
  var eventToCopy = calendarSource.getEvents(start, end);
  
  for (var i in eventToCopy){
    if (eventToCopy[i].getTitle() == "Karfreitag (regionaler Feiertag)"){
      var startDate = eventToCopy[i].getAllDayStartDate();
      startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 4) 
      var endDate = eventToCopy[i].getAllDayEndDate();
      endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 2);

      calendarDestination.createAllDayEvent("Karwoche", startDate, endDate);
      // Exit afterwards
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Sample output:

- My calendar below is the blue one.

[image: sample output]